# How remove Blazor top-row clickable area before user profile name

Tags: html, css, blazor

In blazor default template, after user login, the whole top-row is clickable an anchor element which leads to login/profile page as shown is the image below:
[image]

I tried but I cannot figure out how we can limit this clickable zone to only the profile name text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add `max-width: min-content;` to the `.top-row ::deep a, .top-row ::deep .btn-link` selector in `MainLayout.razor.css`:

```css
.top-row ::deep a, .top-row ::deep .btn-link {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: min-content;
}
```

Comment: adding this to myCustum.css file and ignoring "::deep" did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more an html question than Blazor.
You may disable div href and put the "clickable" area into a button.
You can edit this html on Shared/MainLayout